# Should I be worried about this nvme error-log output?

Tags: 18.04, ssd, nvme

I ran the `nvme error-log /dev/nvme0` command on the terminal. One of the entries gave this output

```
.................
 Entry[ 7]   
.................
error_count  : 18446744069579341823
sqid         : 65535
cmdid        : 0x1
status_field : 0x2(INVALID_OPCODE)
parm_err_loc : 0xffff
lba          : 0xffffffff00040003
nsid         : 0xffffffff
vs           : 255
```

Is this something I need to be worried about? All the other 63 entries had this as their output

```
.................
 Entry[i]   
.................
error_count  : 0
sqid         : 0
cmdid        : 0
status_field : 0(SUCCESS)
parm_err_loc : 0
lba          : 0
nsid         : 0
vs           : 0
.................
```

where `i` is the entry number. I am new to maintaining an ssd's health. If additional information is required, please ask.

Comment: Also seeing similar behavior on my HP SSD EX920 512GB.  Entry 7 reports an error count of an absurdly high number starting with `18446`.  All other entries are fine.  Curious if you were ever able to figure out what was going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. It decodes to an invalid cmd request sent to the controller. Though the error count looks weird! Probably controller encountered some unsupported command or behaved incorrectly to an unimplemented command.
The other 0 field says there are no other errors encountered.